# Distinct don't eliminate null results

Tags: mysql, distinct, group-concat

My application makes use of tables with relationship tables, I use to connect a video with categories,actors and tags GROUP_CONCAT with DISTINCT in my SQL.

The problem I am facing is that I will output thumbs for actors as well but sometimes there is no thumbnail existing yet for the actors. In this case, the values I produce in the row with group_concat are not in line with the actor fields cause 3 actors are unique but if I have 2 actors without an image (null) I lost the anchors to them.

e.g.

```
SELECT
  videos.id AS id, 
  videos.video_title AS video_title,
  videos.video_views AS video_views, 
  videos.video_likes AS video_likes, 
  videos.video_dislikes AS video_dislikes, 
  videos.video_duration AS video_duration,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.actor_name SEPARATOR ';') AS actor_names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_name SEPARATOR ';') AS tag_names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_name SEPARATOR ';') AS category_names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.actor_thumb SEPARATOR ';') AS actor_thumbs

FROM videos 

LEFT OUTER JOIN video_actors  AS va ON va.video_id = videos.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN actor AS a ON a.actor_id = va.actor_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN video_tags AS vt ON vt.video_id = videos.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags AS t ON t.tag_id = vt.tag_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN video_categories AS vc ON vc.video_id = videos.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS c ON c.category_id = vc.category_id

WHERE videos.id = '23'
```

Actor thumb field Results:

```
more fields.. |0;http://site.com/actor/59.jpg
```

But it should be (3 actors, 2 without a thumbnail):

```
more fields.. |0;0;http://site.com/actor/59.jpg
```

To keep the values against actor names in line.

Hope this is a bit clear.

Thanks in advance!
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would probably be best to get the actor name and thumb at once...

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.actor_name,'^',a.actor_thumb) SEPARATOR ';') AS actor_names
```

Comment: Edited the answer, actully my first suggestion wouldnt directly work with distinct.